# Letting EF 4.1 auto-create an identity column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, identity-column

Suppose you have

```
public class A
{
   public string _myString;
}
```

And this context:

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> myASet{ get; set; }
}
```

Now, is there a way to tell EF to generate an identity column for `myASet`?

I don't want to add an ID field to `class A`, so I wonder if EF could do this.
Many thanks,

Juergen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must add ID column** to your class if you want to have it in the database. Also in EF each entity must have mapped primary key.

Comment: The thing is that my class A comes as a result from a WCF service where an ID field would not make any sense since the WCF is unaware of any database issues. So I will have to copy the fields to another class before writing to the DB. Not very efficient...thanks!

Comment: There is no problem with efficiency in your case. It is also quite common to expose different (non entity) types in WCF - that is principle of data transfer objects.

Answer (score 1):

EF will only use columns which are actually in your model classes, so you have to put all the ones you want in yourself. This includes identity columns for primary keys.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an entity called Product and a property called 'ProductId' , EF will automatically add the identity column as it looks for entity name + Id by convention.

You can use a column that does not comply with the convention by adding a [key] attribute above the desired property.

In the example below.  An identity column will be created for ProductId.

```
 public class Product 
 { 
    public int ProductId { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string CategoryId { get; set; } 
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; } 
 }
```

In this example, the column 'MyId' will be created as an identity.

```
 public class Product 
 { 
    [key]
    public int MyId { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string CategoryId { get; set; } 
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; } 
 }
```